# Visual Studio - Range chart - Adding background colours per category group

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, charts

I am using a Range chart to create a Gannt Chart of sorts. I am attempting to do two things:

1) Change the background colour of the range chart based upon one of two Category groups, I have two groups, an outer and an inner, and I would like the background colour to change based on the outer grouping. I have a piece of code that determines a colour but, i'm having trouble applying that to the background. I was hoping interlacing colour would help me, that you aren't able to determine the frequency of the interlacing from what I can tell.

The code I'm using is:

```
Private colorPalette As String() = { "#C85200", "#FF800E", "#5F9ED1",
"#2CA02C", "#A59D93", "#B8341B", "#352F26", "#F1E7D6", "#E16C56", "#CFBA9B"}

Private count As Integer = 0
Private mapping As New System.Collections.Hashtable()

Public Function GetColor(ByVal groupingValue As String) As String
   If mapping.ContainsKey(groupingValue) Then
      Return mapping(groupingValue)
   End If
   Dim c As String = colorPalette(count Mod colorPalette.Length)
   count = count + 1
   mapping.Add(groupingValue, c)
   Return c
End Function
```

2) Position the X and Y axis labels between the major grid lines. The X axis is a date, and the end user would like the date to be between the two grid lines (representing a day) rather than on each grid line, I've had a look around but can't seem to find anything relevant.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for getting back to me, my problem isn't with the code, I'm just after guidance with some of the operations with Visual Studio, I think I covered everything I need in the original post. If I'm in the wrong place then that's fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Robert He didn't specifically ask for anyone to write the code "Any help or guidance would be appreciated, thanks!". If you don't have anything constructive to say, then please don't bother at all. People like you make this site seem unfriendly to new users who are simply looking for "guidance".

Comment: Sorry, @user3650602 this reads like a classic "give me teh codez lol" post to me. Limited research on the OP's side, no attempts. You're welcome to disagree and answer, of course, and I may even upvote your answer.

Comment: Hi @Robert, I would completely agree, if I had asked for any code at all. However I was simply asking if anyone in this community knew if Visual Studio was able to do what I am after. If it's not possible then I shall stop digging, if it is, a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. You said you had trouble applying your code. Can you show what you have tried so far so people don't repeat the same steps.

2. This is form memory but I 'think' there is an Axis and/or tickmark offset value that you can change that will do what you want.

Comment: Hi Alan, apologies for the confusion, the code works fine, and is used in other reports, but not in this manner.

I shall check out the offset values, thanks!